# Gutenberg Block validation failed

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm creating a custom Gutenberg block. It works fine on save and appears on the front end, but as soon I come back to it it reads.

> Block contains invalid or unexpected content

When I go in to resolve the block, I get an extra `figure` inserted around my `MediaUpload` component.

[image: I get an extra <code>figure</code> inserted around my <code>MediaUpload</code> component.]

The console output shows the structure of block except with the text added in.

[image: The console output shows the structure of block except with the text added in.]

I saw a similar issue where the HTML nodes of edit function didn't match up with save function HTML nodes. After seeing that, I doubled check to make sure my nodes lined and I believe they do, unless I'm skipping over something. Here is the code for the block:

```
const { RichText, MediaUpload, PlainText } = wp.editor;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { Button } = wp.components;

import './style.scss';
import './editor.scss';

registerBlockType('stackoverflow/image-card', {
  title: "Image Card",
  icon: 'feedback',
  category: 'common',
  attributes: {
    title: {
      source: 'text',
      selector: '.imageCard__title'
    },
    body: {
      type: 'string',
      source: 'children',
      selector: '.imageCard__body'
    },
    imageAlt: {
      attribute: 'alt',
      selector: '.imageCard__image'
    },
    imageUrl: {
      attribute: 'src',
      selector: '.imageCard__image'
    }
  },



edit({ attributes, className, setAttributes }) {

    const getImageButton = (openEvent) => {
      if(attributes.imageUrl) {
        return (
          <img 
            src={ attributes.imageUrl }
            onClick={ openEvent }
            className="image"
          />
        );
      }
      else {
        return (
          <div className="button-container">
            <Button 
              onClick={ openEvent }
              className="button button-large"
            >
              Pick an image
            </Button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    };

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <MediaUpload
          onSelect={ media => { setAttributes({ imageAlt: media.alt, imageUrl: media.url }); } }
          type="image"
          value={ attributes.imageID }
          render={ ({ open }) => getImageButton(open) }
        />
        <h3>
          <PlainText
            onChange={ content => setAttributes({ title: content }) }
            value={ attributes.title }
            placeholder="Your card title"
            className="heading"
          />
        </h3>
        <div className={className}>
          <RichText
            onChange={ content => setAttributes({ body: content }) }
            value={ attributes.body }
            multiline="p"
            placeholder="Your card text"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
    },

save({ attributes }) {

const cardImage = (src, alt) => {
  if(!src) return null;

  if(alt) {
    return (
      <img 
        className="card__image" 
        src={ src }
        alt={ alt }
      /> 
    );
  }

  // No alt set, so let's hide it from screen readers
  return (
    <img 
      className="card__image" 
      src={ src }
      alt=""
      aria-hidden="true"
    /> 
  );
};

return (
  <div className="container">
    <img 
        className="card__image" 
        src={ attributes.imageUrl }
        alt={ attributes.imageAlt }
      /> 
    <h3 className="card__title">{ attributes.title }</h3>
    <div className="card__body">
      { attributes.body }
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
});
```

Comment: I sometimes have the same bug. Gutenberg automatically adds a figure around the images. Now I myself always add a figure tag for all the images when developing blocks.

Answer (score -1):

On the *edit function* you have an extra **P** element which is absent in *save function*.

```
<RichText
    onChange={ content => setAttributes({ body: content }) }
    value={ attributes.body }
    multiline="p"
    placeholder="Your card text"
/>
```

Also the error is expecting

```
<div class="wp-block-uwec-image-card container card>
```

but getting

```
<div class="wp-block-uwec-image-card card>
```

Fix these two issues

I hope this helps